# How do you store marginal effects using margins command in Stata?

Tags: stata, effects

I'm estimating a regular `probit` model in Stata and using the `margins` command to calculate the marginal effects.

I'm trying to illustrate the change in effects when treating the dummy variables as continuous in my estimate as opposed to treating them as a discrete change from 0 to 1.

```
probit dead dmage dmeduc i.dmar i.foreignb i.mblack i.mhispan i.motherr agesq i.tobacco i.alcohol
margins, dydx(alcohol tobacco) // treating the discrete variables 
margins, dydx(alcohol tobacco) continuous
```

According to the documentation the `margins` command stores the estimates using the `e()`. However when I try and save the estimates after using the `margins` command, regardless of whether I use

```
return list 
ereturn list
```

it just returns the saved post estimation results from my `probit` model and not from the `margins` command.

How do I store the marginal effects values and then put them in a table to show the comparison?

Comment: I don't think Stata has the technical tools to do so, although you could look into Roger Newson's resultssets.

Answer (score 8):

The documentation of `margins` says that the results are returned in e() if you specify the `post` option. So here is an example that does what you want:

```
sysuse auto, clear
gen byte good = rep78 > 3 if !missing(rep78)

probit good i.foreign price
margin , dydx(foreign) post
est store indicator

probit good foreign price
margins , dydx(foreign) post
est store continuous

est table indicator continuous, se
```